# Data validation issues in HTML

Tags: html

I have an HTML data entry code with some data validation. After I enter the customer no and select 'Find' to look for the customer details, it is still asking for the 'customer title'.

How do I resolve this issue?

```html
<HTML>
<BODY bgcolor="AliceBlue">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='input-style.css' type='text/css' />
<form method="post" action="customers.php">
<table width="550px" align = "center">
<colgroup>
    <col span="4"  style="background-color:cyan">
  </colgroup>

<thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Customer Details</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
 </td>
</tr>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="cust_no">Customer No.: </label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="cust_no" maxlength="10" size="10" required>
<input type="submit"  formaction="/find_customers.php" value="Find">   
 </td>
</tr>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="cust_title">Customer Title</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="cust_title" maxlength="10" size="10" required>
 </td>
</tr>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="surname">Surname </label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="surname" maxlength="20" size="20" required>
 </td>
</tr>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="fstname">First Name</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="fstname" maxlength="50" size="30" required>
 </td>
</tr>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="midname">Middle Name</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="midname" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="sex">Sex</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <select name="sex">
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
  </select>

 <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
<input  type="date" name="dob" maxlength="10" size="10" required>
</tr>

</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
  <label for="profession">Profession</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="profession" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>

</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
  <label for="cust_type">Customer Type</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
 <select name="cust_type">
    <option value="Individual">Individual</option>
    <option value="Group">Group</option>
   <option value="Company">Company</option>
  </select>
 </td>
</tr>

</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
  <label for="p_addr1">Postal Address</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="p_addr1" maxlength="20" size="20">
  <input  type="text" name="p_addr2" maxlength="20" size="20">
</tr>

</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
  <label for="l_addr1">Location Address</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="l_addr1" maxlength="20" size="20">
 <input  type="text" name="l_addr2" maxlength="20" size="20">
</tr>

</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
  <label for="phone_no">Phone No.</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="phone_no" maxlength="20" size="20" required>
 </td>
</tr>

</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
  <label for="id_type ">ID Type</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
 <select name="id_type ">
    <option value="Driver's License">Driver's License</option>
    <option value="Passport">Passport</option>
    <option value="National ID">National ID</option>
  </select>

  <label for="id_no ">ID No.</label>
  <input  type="text" name="id_no " maxlength="20" size="20" required>
</tr>
 
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="mon_basic">Monthly Basic Salary</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="number" name="mon_basic" maxlength="5" size="5"  min="0"  step = "any" value="0.00" required>
 </td>
</tr>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="year_basic">Annual Basic Salary</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="number" name="year_basic" maxlength="5" size="5" min="0"  step = "any" value="0.00" required>
  <label for="cust_status ">Customer Status</label>
   <select name="cust_status">
    <option value="Active">Active</option>
    <option value="Dormant">Dormant</option>
    <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
  </select>
</tr>


</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
  <label for="employer">Employer</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="employer" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>

</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
  <label for="emp_addr1">Employer Address</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="emp_addr1" maxlength="20" size="20">
 <input  type="text" name="emp_addr1" maxlength="20" size="20">
</tr>

</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
  <label for="emp_phone">Employer Phone</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="emp_phone" maxlength="20" size="20">
 </td>
</tr>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
     <input type="submit"  formaction="/update_customers.php" value="Update">   
<input type="submit" value="Save">  
</tr>

<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <a href= "loanmgr.html">Main Menu</a>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</HTML>
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to S/O. For future reference after saying what your problem is.. if you also say what you've attempted to fix your problem then your question will be better received.  Looking at your HTML, you've set most of your text boxes as required fields and I guess they are all in the same form. I would assume that when you submit your form to do the find your form is not valid for that reason.

Comment: If you want to get the customer details for autocompleting all other fields, I think you must separate the form. Or use javascript to remove the `required` attribute from the other fields in the same form before submit. In that case, I can provide you a possible solution using javascript.

Comment: Yulio Aleman Jimenez - kindly provide me with the javascript solution

Comment: You probably want to avoid a screenshot of your whole computer showing your personal information.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution using vanilla javascript.

```js
var findSubmit = document.querySelector('input[value="Find"]');

findSubmit.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('input[name="cust_title"]').removeAttribute('required');
  document.querySelector('input[name="surname"]').removeAttribute('required');
  document.querySelector('input[name="fstname"]').removeAttribute('required');
  document.querySelector('input[name="dob"]').removeAttribute('required');
  document.querySelector('input[name="phone_no"]').removeAttribute('required');
  document.querySelector('input[name="id_no"]').removeAttribute('required');
  
  // This two are not necessary, because have a default value
  document.querySelector('input[name="mon_basic"]').removeAttribute('required');
  document.querySelector('input[name="year_basic"]').removeAttribute('required');
});
```

```html
<form method="post" action="customers.php">
    <table width="550px" align = "center">
    <colgroup>
        <col span="4"  style="background-color:cyan">
      </colgroup>

    <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Customer Details</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>

    <tr>
     <td valign="top">
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
     </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td valign="top">
      <label for="cust_no">Customer No.: </label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
      <input  type="text" name="cust_no" maxlength="10" size="10" required>
    <input type="submit"  formaction="/find_customers.php" value="Find">   
     </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td valign="top">
      <label for="cust_title">Customer Title</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
      <input  type="text" name="cust_title" maxlength="10" size="10" required>
     </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td valign="top">
      <label for="surname">Surname </label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
      <input  type="text" name="surname" maxlength="20" size="20" required>
     </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td valign="top">
      <label for="fstname">First Name</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
      <input  type="text" name="fstname" maxlength="50" size="30" required>
     </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td valign="top">
      <label for="midname">Middle Name</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
      <input  type="text" name="midname" maxlength="50" size="30">
     </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td valign="top">
      <label for="sex">Sex</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
      <select name="sex">
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
      </select>

     <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
    <input  type="date" name="dob" maxlength="10" size="10" required>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <label for="profession">Profession</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
      <input  type="text" name="profession" maxlength="30" size="30">
     </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <label for="cust_type">Customer Type</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
     <select name="cust_type">
        <option value="Individual">Individual</option>
        <option value="Group">Group</option>
       <option value="Company">Company</option>
      </select>
     </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <label for="p_addr1">Postal Address</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
      <input  type="text" name="p_addr1" maxlength="20" size="20">
      <input  type="text" name="p_addr2" maxlength="20" size="20">
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <label for="l_addr1">Location Address</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
      <input  type="text" name="l_addr1" maxlength="20" size="20">
     <input  type="text" name="l_addr2" maxlength="20" size="20">
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <label for="phone_no">Phone No.</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
      <input  type="text" name="phone_no" maxlength="20" size="20" required>
     </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <label for="id_type ">ID Type</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
     <select name="id_type ">
        <option value="Driver's License">Driver's License</option>
        <option value="Passport">Passport</option>
        <option value="National ID">National ID</option>
      </select>

      <label for="id_no ">ID No.</label>
      <input  type="text" name="id_no" maxlength="20" size="20" required>
    </tr>
     
    <tr>
     <td valign="top">
      <label for="mon_basic">Monthly Basic Salary</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
      <input  type="number" name="mon_basic" maxlength="5" size="5"  min="0"  step = "any" value="0.00" required>
     </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td valign="top">
      <label for="year_basic">Annual Basic Salary</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
      <input  type="number" name="year_basic" maxlength="5" size="5" min="0"  step = "any" value="0.00" required>
      <label for="cust_status ">Customer Status</label>
       <select name="cust_status">
        <option value="Active">Active</option>
        <option value="Dormant">Dormant</option>
        <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
      </select>
    </tr>


    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <label for="employer">Employer</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
      <input  type="text" name="employer" maxlength="30" size="30">
     </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <label for="emp_addr1">Employer Address</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
      <input  type="text" name="emp_addr1" maxlength="20" size="20">
     <input  type="text" name="emp_addr1" maxlength="20" size="20">
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <label for="emp_phone">Employer Phone</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
      <input  type="text" name="emp_phone" maxlength="20" size="20">
     </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
         <input type="submit"  formaction="/update_customers.php" value="Update">   
    <input type="submit" value="Save">  
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
      <a href= "loanmgr.html">Main Menu</a>
     </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```